# Random walk on non-negative integers

Tags: random-walk

> > Consider the Random walk on the non-negative integers with transition probabilities
> >     $$
> > p_{0,1}=1,~~~p_{i,i+1}=1-r,~~~p_{i,i-1}=r,~~~i\geq 1.
> > $$
> >     Determine $p_{00}^{(n)}$

As far as I see it is
$$
p_{00}^{(2n)}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}(1-r)^{n-1}r^n,~~~~~p_{00}^{(2n-1)}=0~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$.

I would like to know if I am right.

If not, please give me some help.

With greetings

Comment: Do you get the correct results for small $n$?

Comment: For $n=1$ I get $p_{00}^{(2)}=r$ and for $n=2$ I get $p_{00}^{(4)}=2(1-r)r^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $p_{00}^{(n)}$? Is it an asymptotic value of the probability of being at location $n$? Or something else?

Comment: It is the probability of getting from 0 to 0 in n steps.

Comment: @mathfremi: Shouldn't your $p_{00}^{(4)}$ include a $r^2$ term, for the 0-1-0-1-0 walk?

Comment: Yes, right. Hm. Do you have an idea how I can include this in my result?